# Redirect old /%category%/%postname%/ to just /%postname%/

Tags: permalinks, redirect, nginx

I changed my posts permalinks from `/%category%/%postname%/` to `/%postname%/`. Now all my old URLs are not working and I want to redirect them to new structure.

How can I do that? I use nginx

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the process is simple.

First, reset the permalinks to the old permalinks.

Then, using the RankMath plugin, from general settings --> Auto post redirect, activate this option and make it on.

Then, change the permalinks structure to the one you desire, and the plugin will automatically do it for you!